# How can you stop all (and reset the timeline clock) in Tone.js?

Tags: next.js, tone.js

Is there a way to stop all players/oscillators/everything with one command and also reset the timeline clock back to zero in Tone.js?

nb I'm using tone.js as a dynamic import in a next.js app (v12 using pages).